# Inserting many-to-many associations via through table in SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Assuming the following SQL Alchemy models:

```
likes = db.Table('likes',
    db.Column('from_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('to_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    liked_by = db.relationship('User', secondary=likes, foreign_keys=likes.c.to_id, lazy='subquery')
    likes = db.relationship('User', secondary=likes, foreign_keys=likes.c.from_id, lazy='subquery')
```

What's the fastest and easiest way to add many `like` relationship between many `User` objects in a way that won't fail if duplicates are attempted?

My closest solution is:

```
x = [
    {'from_id': 1, 'to_id': 2},
    {'from_id': 2, 'to_id': 3},
    {'from_id': 1, 'to_id': 3},
    ...
]
stmt = likes.insert().values(x)
session.execute(stmt)
session.commit()
```

But this entire transaction will fail if, for example `1 -> 2` already exists. Is there any way to execute this statement in a way that will add new rows in the `likes` table and won't fail on existing rows?

The solution should be performant (i.e. support a bulk insertion). Database is PostgreSQL 10.x if a non-generic answer is needed.

Comment: Btw I think your self referential many-to-many configuration is a bit off: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#self-referential-many-to-many-relationship. Not sure, but perhaps instead of defining foreign keys in use it needs the primary- and secondaryjoins.

Comment: @IljaEverilä you're definitely right, fixing to use primary and secondary joins indeed gives the proper behavior! Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the "upsert" features added to Postgresql somewhat recently. If you simply want to ignore duplicates, use [ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.dml.Insert.on_conflict_do_nothing):

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert

stmt = insert(likes).values(x).on_conflict_do_nothing()
...
```